# Magento 2 rest api to get customer password using customer id

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I want to get customer password using customer id. I developed mobile application. Magento use a backend service. Any options to get customer password using get method.

Comment: Magento password is encrypted text and that is one-way encryption. Maybe that is not helpful for you. Also, the passing a password is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get password directly, as it is saved in encrypted form. However you can use customer entered password to authenticate directly if you are using it in login.

You can use following code to authenticate user using API

```
$email = "customer_email@example.com";
$password = "customer_entered_password_here";

//First get customer by given email
$customerModel = $this->customerCollectionFactory->create();
$customerModel->addAttributeToFilter("email", $email);
$customer = $customerModel->getFirstItem();
/*If no customer found against email, then send error */
if(!$customer->getId()){
    $result["error"] = "Invalid login email/phone or password. (Note: Required format for phone number is: 03XXXXXXXXX)";
    return $result;
}

/* If account is locked return error*/
if ($this->getAuthentication()->isLocked($customer->getId())) {
    $result["error"] = "The account is locked.";
    return $result;
}

try {
    $this->getAuthentication()->authenticate($customer->getId(), $password);
    // phpcs:disable Magento2.Exceptions.ThrowCatch
} catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\InvalidEmailOrPasswordException $e) {
    $result["error"] = "Invalid login or password.";
    return $result;
}
```

where `$this->customerCollectionFactory` is the instance of `\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory`

`$this->getAuthentication()` function is:

```
private function getAuthentication()
{
    if (!($this->authentication instanceof \Magento\Customer\Model\AuthenticationInterface)) {
        return \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\AuthenticationInterface::class
        );
    }
    return $this->authentication;
}
```

I have used this process to login a customer into APP